# Reposition swipe-to-delete button in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview with custom-designed cells and thus if I add the swipe-to-delete buttons the layout is horrible. Is it possible to reposition these buttons inside the cell?

Comment: I just wanted to move it a little up and to the left a tiny bit so it fit nicely into my custom designed cell. It doesn't deviate that much from the original button, the look stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO it is not possible to made any changes with delete button because it is built-in or default functionality of Apple iOS. So better to stop fighting with it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not try that, you are not supposed to alter Apple's default views .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the button.

Maybe this code can help you. Write the following code in yourCustomCell.m

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state 
  {
      [super willTransitionToState:state];
      if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) 
      {
          for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) 
          {
              if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"]) 
              {
                  UIImageView *deleteBtn = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 33)];
                  [deleteBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:<yourCustomImage.png>]];
                  [[subview.subviews objectAtIndex:0] addSubview: deleteBtn];
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

You can set the frame of `UIImageView`.

Comment: And when a future update to iOS comes out, this code is likely to break.

Comment: @Krumelur What do you mean "so what?"? It's a bad idea to dig into the private subview structure of standard components. Apple's docs even tell you not to do it. Every year when a new version of iOS comes out, code like in this answer gets broken. Use only public APIs to customize UI components or deal with fragile code that could break at any time and annoy all of your customers.

Comment: With this code I can change the background and the size of the button but not the position and that's what I wanted